# run callback on factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, mongoid, factory-bot

I have a callback in my `user.rb` model something like:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
   .
   .
   .
   .
    #add a first board for user
    after_create :first_board
      def first_board
        board = self.boards.new(:title => self.username, :category_id => Category.find_or_create_by(slug: "other"))
        board.save!
      end
end
```

When a user is created, the app create a new board with above callback.

In my `spec/factories/users.rb` I have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Test User'
    username 'test username'
    password 'please'
    password_confirmation 'please'
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

In my `spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb` I have:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  before :each do
    request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  before (:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET 'show'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should find the right user" do
      get :show, :id => @user.slug
      assigns(:user).should == @user
    end

  end

end
```

**How can I run my callback with factorygirl?**

**I get 2 errors:**

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
       Connection refused - connect(2)
     # (eval):2:in `post'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:190:in `first_board'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
     Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
       Connection refused - connect(2)
     # (eval):2:in `post'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:190:in `first_board'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find_or_create_by method can't be called like that, afaik. It uses method_missing and expects an activerecord attribute tacked on the end. Try:

`Category.find_or_create_by_slug("other")`

Comment: Sorry but it does not works fine for me this fix. You can see in mongoid doc `find_or_create_by` http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html. This method does works fine.

Comment: I see. You might want to add a mongoid tag to your question.